# Derivative of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose that we are given a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ which are non-negative, integrate to $1$ and supported on intervals $[-x_n,x_n]$ with $\sum_{n \geq 1} x_n$ converging where $x_n \geq 0$ for every $n$. If we set $F_n;=f_1 *\cdots *f_n$, where $*$ denotes convolution, is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n$ is differentiable?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n\ge 1} x_n$?  Why do you think that $F_{\infty}$ might be differentiable?  What makes you think that the limit even exists?  Do you have any thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I fixed it. Sorry! The limit exists as a uniform limit. Each $f_n$ is compacty supported, each has integral equal to 1, and the fact that the $x_n$ converge as a series protects the modulus of continuity from getting too large. I've also seen an example where the limit happens to be diffetentiable, but I imagined it wouldn't hold in general.

Comment: Your comment is all really good *context* which should be included in the question.